# How to upload your own font on html?

Tags: html

i remember my IT teacher saying something about if i wanted to download my own font and put it on my website i will need to upload the font file as well. Thats straightforward but if i wanted to host my website how would i go about this?
Thanks

Comment: google have a lot of example

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking here. Can you add more details to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The way you control the fonts used in you HTML is through CSS. To use a custom font, you must first define it in the CSS like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(somefont.otf);
}
```

After defining it, you can use it by applying it in other CSS like so:

```
div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

The font files that are generally used are TrueType (.ttf) or OpenType (.otf). There are other types that a proprietary, such as *.eot (Internet Explorer).

You will need to upload these font files along with the other files such as .html, .css, .js etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to implement font on a website, but first I would strongly recommend reading few articles as [using font-face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), [base64 embedding fonts in css](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri) and [Getting started with Google fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started). I am sure everything will be clear than.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make add costum font support for all type of browser then you should firstly convert the costum font to other font formats like eot, woff, etc. There are a couple of online converters that do that (they will autogenerate actualy the css rules to add to your site.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?-jvpy8e');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-jvpy8e') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?-jvpy8e') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?-jvpy8e') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?-jvpy8e#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```